# Updating product attribute type programmatically

Tags: product-attribute

I have a product attribute that is currently produces `varchar(255)` as a Type in `catalog_product` flat tables. How do I change it to being type `int(11)` programatically? Do I just remove an attribute and re-add it via setup script or there is another way?

Comment: Which your Magento version?

Comment: Magento ver.   1.14

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new attribute
2. Insert new values or copy values from old attribute
3. Delete old attribute
4. (Optional) If you like rename old attribute.

Comment: it sounds very inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Although technically you could directly modify the attribute in the **eav_attribute** table, the real problem is that the combination *product - attribute - value* is actually in **catalog_product_entity_varchar**. So, change attribute type, implicates that all the stored in **catalog_product_entity_varchar** as **varchar(255)** would have to be moved to **catalog_product_entity_int** and converted to **int(11)**. Therefore, there is as such an automatic and enjoyable way to do this, except, indeed, delete and recreate it.

To keep all information already captured in each product, you should perhaps try to export the data, delete the attribute, create it again with the same name, and then re-import the CSV.